# Is there any problem if i copy ubuntu partition to any other partiotions?

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, gparted

is there any problem if i copy ubuntu partition and paste it to another patition and deleted the original ubuntu partition using gparted from live usb

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get what your trying to say, but I'm guessing you want to reinstall Ubuntu to a different partition and keep all of your settings, programs and files.

So what you should do is:

1. Boot up your Ubuntu installation and create a back-up using the back-up utility you can find in the System Settings.
2. Shut down after backing up your system and boot up the live-usb.
3. Go in to Live Mode and start GParted.
4. MAKE SURE YOU HAVE EVERYTHING BACKED UP and then delete your existing Ubuntu partition. (And create a new one/swap around others, if necessary.)
5. Then reinstall Ubuntu with the installer.
6. Then on your new Ubuntu installation put back all of your settings, programs and files with the back-up utility.